Visual Studio Code has infinite reload of .csproj file
I've written an ASP.NET web app in Visual Studio. But now I'm following a tutorial about how to create a Dockerfile, and that tells me to switch to VS Code.  I'm now being bothered by a notification popping up every second:  "There were problems loading project MyProj.csproj. See log for details". I press the [Show C# logs] button and see:

[Warn  - 12:28:42 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Warning while
loading c:\Proj\Supval\CS\Native\Native.csproj: Package
'LightweightExcelReader.Framework 0.1.0.11' was restored using
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework
'net7.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with
your project. [Info  - 12:28:42 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem]
Completed (re)load of all projects in 00:00:01.2954407

This repeats every second, filling up the log file.  The notification is annoying and I worry that something is configured seriously badly. I'm not asking for a solution to the warning, it's only a warning after all - not an error, I'm asking how to stop VS Code doing this infinite reload of my .csproj file. Any ideas?  Am I the only one this has ever happened to?
VS Code Help > About gives:

Version: 1.90.1 (user setup) Commit:
611f9bfce64f25108829dd295f54a6894e87339d Date:
2024-06-11T21:01:24.262Z Electron: 29.4.0 ElectronBuildId: 9593362
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156 Node.js: 20.9.0 V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621


The same was happening to me with a WPF project and restarting VS Code didn't fix the problem.
What worked for me was going to Extensions and disabling the 'C#' extension. Then, click the 'Restart Extensions' box that appears next to it (or restart VS Code), followed by re-enabling the extension again.
This stopped VS Code from attempting to reload the project in a continuous loop.

I tried this and it didn't work but then I tried again and it did. Or maybe it was restarting VS Code after disabling "C# Extensions", and re-enabling it, which fixed it for me. Btw, for others, "Extensions" is gotten via the 4-squares icon on the left vertical strip.

A reload of the plugin is definitely required, either by clicking the 'Restart Extensions' box that appears next to the C# extension, or by restarting VSCode. i'll update the answer, thanks.
